# Console Input Inside WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get console input from inside a WPF application.  In the Project properties I've set it as a console application and the output works.  However, now I want to be able to read input from the console since I haven't started working on the views yet.  I found this snippet on here, but I don't believe it's what I was looking for:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\csc.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use `Console.ReadLine()`?

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It's not a console app.  There needs to be another thread that handles the console.

Comment: @keelerjr12: Have you set a startup object for the console application?

Comment: @keelerjr12: I don't think I understand exactly what you are trying to do. I created a WPF project, set the output type to 'Console Application', and `Console.ReadLine()` works just fine to me.